# After scaling the target & many other variables, while predicting how to descale the target variable to get the actual predicted value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, scaling

I am using sklearn.preprocessing.minmaxscaler to scale the variables. Now, after evaluating the model and selecting the appropriate model, i want to see the actual predicted values. Is it okay to just descale it, will it give me correct predictions or do i need to do something else.

Comment: normally you scale your independent variables, so if you did not scale your dependent variable, why do you need to "descale" ?

Comment: I scaled dependent variable too, Am i not suppose to scale/transform it?